# Embed AWS QuickSight dashboards in native or hybrid mobile applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

Is there a way that I can embed QuickSight dashboards in a native or hybrid mobile application? I had embed it in my web application but I don't know how I can do the same for mobile applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer from AWS support team:**

Unfortunately, as such QuickSight doesn’t support mobile embedding natively. I sincerely apologize on behalf of AWS for any inconvenience caused due to the limitations of the service.

However, using any one of the below workarounds, you should be able to achieve your use case of embedding QuickSight dashboard(s) in Hybrid mobile application(s).

## Option 1

Embed via web view and the web view is within the app. However please note that in using this approach, you might not be able to use the JS SDK that is available to interact with the embedded dashboard from the parent website.

OR

## Option 2

Embed via web view and the web view is in a iframe which is within the mobile app.  please note that in using this approach, you might be able to use the JS SDK but can have performance lag due to the chain: dashboard in a web view in iframe in a mobile app.

Comment: How to set up a domain in Domains and Embedding for web view in mobile application then? We are trying to embed quicksight dashboard in Android/iOS web view but receiving error: Refused to frame 'https://us-east-1.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors ...